# Can a process read a file if the executable file performs reading operation?

Tags: unix, chmod

Disclaimer: this is part of a homework discussion

When `Bob` invokes the executable file, can the process read the following file if the executable indeed performs a reading operation on the file?

```
-rw-r----- 1 hr staff 9678 Nov 15 /company/hr/employeeinfo
```

From the file permissions, I can concluded that read is enabled for Others which is what Bob is, but execution isn't.

My answer for the question (I am not sure if it is correct): Bob cannot invoke the process, since the reading is done within the file which must first be executed, execution permission must first be enabled.

Or is it possible to invoke the process with just read?

Answer (score 0):

If this file is program on some interpretative language like `bash`, `awk` it is possible to run this program by explicitly run the interpreter. For example

```
bash /company/hr/employeeinfo
```

will run the program inside. But you can't execute this program on this way (no exec permission):

```
/company/hr/employeeinfo
```

And there is no problem (if this is a script) to make it read itself